# Slow query using Pyhs2 to fetch data in Hive

Tags: hive, hql, thrift

I tried to use Pyhs2 to communicate with Hive，fetch data and put them in a list(temporary stored in RAM).

But it took a long time to query a table using very simple HQL like 'select fields1,fields2... from table_name', in which data scale is about 7 million rows and less then 20 fields. The whole process costs nearly 90 mins.

My server: CentOS 6.5, 8 cpu units, 32 processors and 32GB RAM
Hadoop cloud: more than 200 machines

Can someone help to solve this problem? Thanks very much

Comment: Have you indexed your table?